# How do I add an existing directory structure to a visual studio 2013 solution

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I have a large directory structure I want to add to a solution. I can't drag the folder into the solution explorer, and there is no button to 'show all files'.

Answer (score 0):

It´s very simple, first copy all directories where you want.

Then open your solution, and select the project that you want add these folders. Go to Project Menu and do click in show all files.

Now you can see your folders in solution explorer.

Next right click in folder and include in project.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not have a project, because the type of project is not an option. I want to add the structure to the solution without intermediate projects.